# Slow running query using date range on non-clustered index column

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I have a very slow running query, and I've isolated the problem down to the following SQL.

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
    TableA a(nolock) 
    inner join TableB b with(nolock) on (b.Id = a.Id AND b.Date>= isnull(@timestamp_start, '17530101') AND b.Date < isnull(@timestamp_end, '99991231'))
```

- a = 2million+ rows
- b = 2million+ rows
- b.Id => Index, unique, non-clustered
- a.Id => Index, unique, non-clustered
- b.Date  => Index, non-unique, non-clustered

This takes several minutes without returning a result even for a single day date range.

**UPDATE:**

The *estimated* execution plan on the production server is showing me this, which shows that a complete scan of a huge table (TableA) is occurring near the beginning of the query, rather than the TableB.date range being used to filter in the WHERE. Why is this happening and how can I force the query to filter first on my date range?

[image]

The plan relates to this query, which in detail is:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
    TableA a(nolock) 
    inner join TableB b with(nolock) on (b.Id = a.Id AND b.Date>= isnull(@timestamp_start, '17530101') AND b.Date < isnull(@timestamp_end, '99991231'))
    inner join TableC c with(nolock) on c.Id2 = s.Id2 and c.Id3 = a.Id3 and c.Id = b.Id
    inner join TableD d with(nolock) on (a.DealId = d.Id and d.Id3 = s.Id3 AND (@myparam is null OR d.ProviderName = @myparam))
    inner join TableE e with(nolock) on (e.Id = d.Id AND (@myparam2 is null OR e.Id = @myparam2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the actual plan, not to the estimated one that you posted here.

Your plan uses NL with lookups in the clustered index + sorts, so it's clear the server estimated small number of rows for your filters. When you look at the actual plan and instead of 100-1000 rows see there 500.000 rows go out from your first index seek, there is a problem. It means that full scan should be used, and hash join instead of merge.

So update your post with the actual plan please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63253/discussion-between-chris-halcrow-and-sepupic).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found out that for a complex query like this, since SQL server will cache the last execution plan, a later query can end up being poorly optimised.

I'd previously run the query using one of the parameters, and the execution plan was optimizing for that scenario on *subsequent* queries. By adding the following to the end of the query, SQL server is forced to recompile an execution plan for the query, and this fixes the performance:

```
OPTION  (RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Another approach to address varying search conditions is dynamic SQL. See http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html.